# Seeking closed form for $\sum\sum\left\lfloor\frac{kr}{n-1} \right\rfloor$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to get a closed form for 
$$f(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}\left\lfloor\frac{kr}{n-1} \right\rfloor$$

It is fairly obvious that for large $n$ this grows like $\frac{n^2}{6}$ but for a step in a problem I am working I need this in in some sort of closed form, or at least a simpler form or single sum.

When I try it, totients come into the picture, but I seem to get ugly sums of totients, and that is not much better than the original double sum.

It doesn't seem like this should be so tough.

Comment: I can't reproduce the growth you mention. What are the first few values of $f(n)$?

Comment: I get $0,0,1,3,7,14,25,38,58,83,116,152,202,254,\ldots$.

Comment: The reason it should go as $n^2/6$ can be seen if you drop the floor function and replace the sums by integrals.